# Getting error while installing 64bit Windows 7 on pre-installed in-build 64 bit Windows 10

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, windows-8, boot

I am using ASUS dual core laptop with 2GB Ram, 500GB hard disk & Windows 10 in-build. My laptop is lagging because of my Windows 10. When I buy this laptop it has in-build windows 10. Now when I want to use Windows 7 in my laptop then I am getting "required file is missing" error & setup is canceled in between & automatically windows 10 starts. I had attached the screenshot of the error that I am getting. I am getting this error when I am booting windows 7 in my laptop which also has Windows 10. Is there any solution to this.

[image]

Comment: You are attempting to install Windows 7 in UEFI mode but Windows 10 is installed on a MBR partition, hence the reason, your EFI drivers are missing from the EFI partition.  If that isn't the case then provide additional information because that appears to be the case based on the screenshot.  You are going to need to format and delete your existing partitions, and then install Windows 7.

Comment: No I have Windows 10 installed, so I want to removed that & install Windows 7

Comment: What type of additional information you want

Comment: I corrected my comment.  I provided a way ahead.  If my understanding of the problem is not correct, then provide the information, required to make your current configuration known to us.  What you provide is entirely up to you, if my understanding is not correct, then it clearly isn't enough information

Comment: Are you installing 32-bit or 64-bit Windows? Laptops with 2GB RAM often come with a 32-bit OS, and that usually means the UEFI firmware can only boot 32-bit loaders - even if your CPU is 64-bit.

Comment: I am installing 64 bit Windows

Comment: @Ramhound When I am booting 64-bit Windows 7 on Windows 10 then this problem occur

Comment: Do you have a full backup of your system?  It might be a lot easier of you just completely wiped the drive and tried re-installing with a clean drive if you haven't already.

Comment: R u telling me to clean cdrive & reinstall the Windows 7

Comment: @SalmanDalal - You want to install Windows 7 on your device.  How you do that is, you format your storage device, and install Windows 7.  That requires you to lose your existing installation.  It is not clear what you have actually done, if all you are doing is booting to a Windows 7 installation disk, then you have skipped several steps.

Comment: Is your existing Win10 OS 32-bit? Also, is that error when you boot the install disc, or when you boot the OS after install? (@Ramhound, it is generally not necessary to wipe the disk first - you can do so from within the Windows installer.)

Comment: @Bob I had i in-build Windows 10 OS & when I am trying to change the OS from Windows 10 to Windows 7 this error occur. I am booting windows 7 from USB that has the Windows 7 setup in it

Comment: @Bob this error comes when I try to install Windows 7 using USB that has a setup of Windows 7

Comment: The question is whether your "in-build" Windows 10 is 32-bit or 64-bit. If it's 32-bit you'll probably have to find a 32-bit copy of Windows 7. Either that or don't install in UEFI mode.

Comment: I have a 64bit Windows 10 inbuilt

Comment: @Bob any answer to this

Comment: In that case, I don't know, sorry. You can try making sure your installer drive is correctly created, and maybe follow @Ramhound's suggestion of wiping the existing disk first.

Comment: After wiping out the disk do UEFI mode accept the installation from the USB drive